# Java file class

Tags: java, file

I`m trying to write java program that take license number from one file and put it in another file. This what I wrote until now:

```
import java.io.File;

import java.util.Formatter;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class license {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        openFile();
        readFileAndConvert();
    }

    private static Scanner x;

    // Open original license file

    public static void openFile() {

        try {
            x = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\originalLicense.txt"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public static void readFileAndConvert() {

        String licenseNum;
        Formatter newLicense = null;

        while (x.hasNext()) {
            licenseNum = x.next();

            if (licenseNum == "123") {  

                try {
                    newLicense = new Formatter("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\newLicense.txt");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
                newLicense.format("%", licenseNum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used youtube videos to write this and now I can`t find the problem, Is anybody can guess what can be the problem?

Comment: Do not use `==` to compare strings, as you are doing in `if (licenseNum == "123")`. See: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839)

Comment: Please provide the error you get

Comment: I didn`t get, nothing happend..

Answer (score 0):

```
newLicense.format("%", licenseNum);
```

This is not a valid format string. Did you mean `"%s"`?

NB Don't use `==` to compare `String` values. Use `.equals()`.

Did you consider consulting the documentation? Don't waste your time trying to learn computer programming from YouTube.

Comment: Thank you I changed this both. But i`m still having a problem to debug, you can assume what it can be?